# How to make /proc/net/arp accessible?

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, proc, snmp

The snmpd service on my debian system doesn't deliver traffic information of the network adapters. I found the following message in the syslog:
snmpd: Cannot open /proc/net/arp

When I execute now "cat /proc/net/arp" as root the content is shown. But not when I run the command using any other user.
Since the snmpd service is running under it's own user the error message above makes sense.

I know, that the kernel is restricting the access to the virtual folder /proc. But how can I find out why it's restricted and how to remove such restriction?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe apparmor. This is configured in /etc/apparmor.d

Comment: @icarus apparmor is not installed